# Eclipse: Extension Point for Run As

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

for my custom launcher, I need the info which extension point is needed for run custom application. Similar like the JavaApplication.

[image]

Comment: That menu is just built by matching the contextualLaunch expression in launch shortcuts with the current selection, there is no separate extension point. `org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.ContextualLaunchAction`

Comment: ok just fixed my problem